# Jquery. Why this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is html code:

```
                   <a class="cat" href="#">category</a>
                 <span class="kiti" style="position:absolute; padding:5px; margin-left:-18px; display:none; background-color:#000">
                    <a href="#">sub1</a>
                    <br /><a href="#">sub2</a>
                    </span>
```

And functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $(".cat").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().slideDown(300);  
  });
  $(".cat").mouseout(function() {
    $('.kiti').slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

How to make, that it would allow to press sub1 and sub2, because when I try it, sub-category hides. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $(".cat").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().stop().slideDown(300);
  }, function() {
    $(this).next().stop().slideUp(300);
  });
});
```

[`hover()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) takes two callbacks: the first is for when the mouse is over the element(s). The second is for when the mouse leaves.

Note that you also had some missing semi-colons and other syntactic problems.

Also, it's advisable to [`stop()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/stop) animations in this kind of situation otherwise with quickly firing events you may not get the desired result.

Lastly, I'm not entirely convinced `slideUp` and `slideDown` will behave as desired with inline elements (being that `<span>` as opposed to block-level elements). Come to think of it, that's probably the root cause of your problems. From [`slideUp()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideUp#speedcallback):

> Hide all matched elements by adjusting
>   their height and firing an optional
>   callback after completion.

Inline elements don't respond to height adjustments. So you should use a `<div>` or make that particular `<span>` `display: block`.

Comment: Doesn't work neither yours neither karim's. Maybe I need to add one id or what, i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You're not applying `hover` correctly. It takes two functions as arguments (mouseover and mouseout). Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cat").hover(function() { 
        $(this).next().slideDown(300); 
    }, function() { 
        $('.kiti').slideUp(300);     
    });
});
```

or the plain mouseover/mouseout equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cat").mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).next().slideDown(300); 
    }).mouseout(function() { 
        $('.kiti').slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't write the same as you did. Did you copy/paste the code from here?